# Reading Hex Values from file (C++)

Tags: c++, file, hex

I've been struggling with this one for a while now.  I'm trying to read a file with hexadecimal information in it, lets say the contents of the file looks like this.

```
00 00 e0 3a 12 16 00 ff fe 98 c4 cc ce 14 0e 0a aa cf
```

I'm looking for a method of reading each 'byte' of information (whilst ignoring whitespace) in C++.

Since the code I'm writing is part of a class I've created a small program to demonstrate what I'm currently doing.

```
int main(void)
{
     int i = 0;
     unsigned char byte;
     unsigned char Memory[50];
     ifstream f_in;
     f_in.open("file_with_hex_stuff.txt");

     f_in >> skipws; // Skip Whitespace
     while(f_in >> hex >> byte)
     {
         Memory[i++] = byte;   
     }
     return 0;
}
```

(apologies if the code above doesn't compile, it's just so you can get a feel for what I'm wanting.
I expected the array to be like this:

```
Memory[0] => 0x00;
Memory[1] => 0x00;
Memory[2] => 0xe0;
Memory[3] => 0x3a;
Memory[4] => 0x12;
```

etc....

But instead it loads each of the numbers into it's own position in the array like this:

```
Memory[0] => 0x00;    // 2 LOCATIONS USED FOR 0x00
Memory[1] => 0x00;    // 

Memory[2] => 0x00;    // 2 LOCATIONS USED FOR 0x00
Memory[3] => 0x00;    //

Memory[4] => 0x0e;    // 2 LOCATIONS USED FOR 0xe0
Memory[5] => 0x00;    //

Memory[6] => 0x03;    // 2 LOCATIONS USED FOR 0x3a
Memory[7] => 0x0a;    //
```

etc...

Applogies if this post makes no sense.  Any feedback appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your output, your program is reading one hex digit at a time.

Try reading into an `unsigned int` instead:

```
unsigned int value;
while (f_in >> hex >> value)
{
  byte = ((unsigned char) (value & 0xff);
  Memory[i++] = byte;
  //...
}
```

Also, try using a debugger to explore your code.  For example, you could add `value` and `byte` as *watch* variables and single step through your code.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/drfkTO)

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, this has worked a treat!